# what is the format of a binary image & how is it different from jpg, png images?

Tags: image, bitmap, binary, format, .doc

I searched the internet for the basic formats of image files (e.g. .jpg, .png, .gif) as there is a specific format for .doc, .pdf etc. But didn't got anything relevant. And today I also came with an .bin image format. BIN signifies that the image is in the Binary format. So, what is the Internal format of .jpg image file. And How is it different from .bin (Binary) format. Because everything is Basically saved in Binary Form. And How is BITMAP Image different from .jpg format.

Comment: Are you saying you didn't find usable info on the formats [jpg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg) [png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and [gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gif)??  All three have their Wikipedia pages (just click on the 3 extensions above) containing at least basic format information, references to the relevant standards and pointers to (reference) implementations.  So I find your statement extremely puzzling.

Comment: Thank you @fvu. Don't know why wkipedia links didn't came up in the search. Its the Exact info I needed. But Theres no information on Binary Image

Answer (score 1):

if you open the files in notepad or change the jpg to .txt and a exe to .txt you will see the first X amount of bytes defines what type of file it is etc.  I have never looked into where the "standard" is but as you will see all JPEGS start with a specific byte and EXE start with a specific byte no matter what the content

Also JPEG is a licensed compressed form of an image and BMP is Microsoft Windows version of an image(with little or no compression I believe.  png is open source or GPL licensed and technically your files do not need to be "licensed" to convert to JPEG.   This is the same as a .MP3 vs a.OGG in terms of music

Comment: be careful with your analogies: mp3 vs ogg is lossy format vs a file container (ogg files can contain an audio stream encoded in the lossy Vorbis format). Jpg is lossy, whereas png isn't.  PNG the format is patent- and license free, the reference implementation libpng comes under an [open source license](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html).  Not commenting on the JPEG situation although [I have serious doubts](http://www.jpeg.org/faq.phtml?action=show_answer&question_id=q3f042a5e42fd8) :